# I need to iterate Parallel for loop on StreamReader ReadLine() but stuck at multiple thread access to object

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I tried by creating the stream reader object (`sr`) inside the parallel for loop. It's working but taking 1.3 minutes to fetch data which should have been fetched under 4 seconds. The problem as I hope is somewhere related to this `StreamReader` object. When tried with below code I am getting an error which I tried many way to solve but currently very much stuck at it. Even used concurrent bags, `volatile`, `ThreadStatic` and `lock`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread th0 = new Thread(() => ReadAllLinesAsync(
            @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Fnale mail\LineDataBackHigh.csv"));
        th0.Start();
        th0.Join();
        watch.Stop();
        Debug.Log("time=" + watch.Elapsed);
        Debug.Log("Finished Task + ");
    });

    Debug.Log("Free Executed, Task Independent");
}

public static string[] ReadAllLinesAsync(string path)
{
    ConcurrentBag<string> lines = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    // Open the FileStream with the same FileMode, FileAccess
    // and FileShare as a call to File.OpenText would've done.
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        string line = String.Empty;
        int k = 0;
        sr8 = sr;

        Thread th0 = new Thread(Fetch);

        th0.Start();
        th0.Join();
        Debug.Log("Finished Reading2" + lines.Count);
        int item = 1;

        void Fetch()
        {
            Parallel.For(k, File.ReadLines(path).Count(), z =>
            {
                sr8 = sr;
                Debug.Log("Executing");
                lines.Add(sr8.ReadLine());
                // sr.Dispose();
            });
        }
    }
    return lines.ToArray();
}
```

Error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to stop and ask yourself why you are using all the different concepts you've employed. Why Task.Run, why a new Thread, why a ConcurrentBag etc. From what I can tell you can replace all your code with File.ReadLines().

Comment: Cant you see my purpose on my question ? I have different needs of integrating all these concepts and i cant share why and only one of my need is fetching data.

Comment: Could you replace the images with the actual code? Posting code is much preferable to posting images.

Comment: ofcourse, i will do that!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to parallelize the [`File.ReadLines`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) method, so that you can read the lines of a file by multiple threads in parallel. Unfortunately this is not easy to do. And even if you find a way to do it, for example by opening the file with multiple `StreamReader`s at different positions, and splitting manually the lines after decoding the bytes, there is no guarantee that you'll get any performance boost. On the contrary it is quite possible that reading the file will be significantly slower, because of how frequently the heads of the hard disk will have to jump from sector to sector.

My advice is to just use the `File.ReadLines` method as is, and find other places in your code that can be optimized for performance.

Answer (score 0):

actually, there is a [nice solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern) for this build into the .net framework that uses the consumer pattern

first, you create a producer something like this

```
static void Produce(ITargetBlock<string> target, Stream stream)
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string? line = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) is not null)
    {
        target.Post(line);//tells the comsumet there is something to read
    }

    target.Complete();//tells consumer done filling
}
```

when the "writing of the data" is done you can generate the task that will be used to read the buffer, so let's create the consumer

```
static async Task ConsumeAsync(ISourceBlock<string> source)
{
    //reads the data in a non-blocking way
    while (await source.OutputAvailableAsync())
    {
        string line = await source.ReceiveAsync();

        //do your magic here                
    }   
            
}
```

now let's connect the 2 methods and execute the consumer-producer pattern

```
using var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Resources.LargeFile.csv");
if (stream is null)
    throw new ResourceNotFoundException("LargeFile.csv", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());


var buffer = new BufferBlock<string>();
var consumerTask = ConsumeAsync(buffer);
Produce(buffer, stream);
await consumerTask;
```

Imagine you need to process a file larger than available memory... this will fill up based on the speed you read the stream vs the speed you process the read strings... you may run out of memory.. not as fast as reading all and doing parallel processing but you will/may eventually get into problems.

as for timing, I parse a CSV file into a .Net class using this pattern in 6 seconds what takes several minutes using the pattern just by improving the locking. the more locking overhead the better the performance.

Comment: "the more locking overhead the better the performance' - whaat?